# white box appears when scrolling

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, scrolling

Over the last couple of weeks whenever I go to scroll up or down a page half of the page suddenly goes white and I can often see like a grey checked pattern (I'm sorry if that doesn't make sense, not quite sure how to explain this) that will suddenly appear and then disappear and the page is back to normal, I was told to try and clear my cache and cookies and I did, but it's still doing it, it only happens for a second or two before going back to normal, and it's not usually all the page, just half of it. But it's really annoying and I don't know why it's doing that and what to do to fix  it.

Hopefully someone knows what I'm talking about lol.

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: No, it just happens in Chrome.